How to pin to the Task Bar the Device Manager on Windows 11?
After launching the device manager I can't right click it and pin it to the Task Bar like other programs. Any ideas?

I created a new shortcut on the desktop. I pasted in "devmgmt.msc". I dragged the shortcut to the Task Bar.

FYI - it's there in right-click start menu - guess that's two clicks not one :D

It's in the right-click menu for everything else I tried but not this particular one for some reason. Very odd behavior.


Find "C:\Windows\System32\devmgmt.msc"
Right click it, "Show More Options"
Pin to Taskbar.

